# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

When i send:

```
Result = CInt(NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer))
```

I receive (SOME TIMES) this error:

```
Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

What exactly means that? and how i can resolve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that `CInt` argument is out of range of `Integer`, -0x80000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF
And it happens when `NetApiBufferFree` returns an error: error codes are bigger than 0x80000000.

There is no unsigned int32 type, so use `CLng` instead of `CInt`.

---

About source of error.  You should find out code of error which you get: call MsgBox or log it to file, or use breakpoint. Next find its description. If it won't help you (for example error would be E_FAIL), add code to check that `pBuffer` value is valid - that it wasn't modified by something, and wasn't already freed. Add logging for `NetApiBuffer*` calls.

Comment: +1. Also make sure `Result` is actually declared as a `Long`. Additionally turn on `Option Strict` so that the compiler warns you when you might be vulnerable to this sort of thing.

Comment: Dear Abyx thank you very much for your answer which accurate but it's not point me to the source of my problem, I mean by that what i have to do in order to handle this error? For the moment i have suspend the instruction for Buffer Free until i see how to handle it. Can you assist me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is replace 'double' in place of 'Int16/Int32/Int64'

some times file conversion takes huge numbers.. double never has maximum range.